# What is subtopology in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I've been exploring the sources of Kafka Streams and have hard time understanding what operators would make for one or many sub-topologies (and then [node groups](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c3475081c5e8228e9bd3a45022a93d61e542f72e/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/InternalTopologyBuilder.java#L836-L841)). Can someone explain what to use so [Topology.describe](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c3475081c5e8228e9bd3a45022a93d61e542f72e/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/InternalTopologyBuilder.java#L1371-L1387) shows sub-topologies?

What are sub-topologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems Apache Kafka docs don't describe them in detail... There is a section in Confluent docs about it: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html#stream-partitions-and-tasks

> Sub-topologies (also called sub-graphs): [...] A sub-topology is a set of processors, that are all transitively connected as parent/child or via state stores in the topology. Hence, different sub-topologies exchange data via topics and don’t share any state stores. [...]

A *node group* is the internal name of a sub-topology.

Sub-topologies are scaled independently, i.e., each sub-topology may have a different number of instantiations (so-called *tasks*) depending on the maximum number of partitions over all its input topics.

Comment: Can you show an example of multiple topologies? Say I have 5 streams from 5 different topics and they do a select key, repartition and transform. Are those considered subtopologies? Does that create 6 sub topologies? 5 total for the repartitions and one topology for all 5 transforms? Does that mean the transforms are being processed by one task / single thread per partition?

Comment: It's always hard to say without seeing the code. But you can use `Topology#describe()` to inspect the structure of your program; it reveals the sub-topology structure.

Comment: Are all items within one subtopology ran one task one thread per partition ? Meaning if there were two topics that shared a state store, only one (depth first) topic would be processed at a time, synchronously between the two topics, alternating processing time?

Comment: Yes, that correct. KS picks the next record to be processed based on the extracted record timestamp (lower timestamp first -- if there are two records with the same timestamp, there is no guarantee which one will be picked).